# React tutorial - how do I start the node server for a reactJs application?

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, localhost

I'm just starting the react.js tutorial, I've downloaded the files and then it mentions:

"Follow your progress by opening http://localhost:3000 in your browser (after starting the server). "

I know this may sound stupid, (bear with me since I'm a beginner with React) but how do I start the server in this instance?

Thanks.

Marc

Comment: Depends on what language you are using: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/

Comment: How about link to the repo/tutorial??

Answer (score 25):

Pretty solid chance it's `npm start` from the project root.

Properly packaged modules will have some [node scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) configured in `package.json`. It's customary to use `start` as the script to run the dev environment, though some might use `build`, `dev`, or other names.

Comment: Basically I come from a creative background, having branched into front end design and development 12 years ago so having comercial experience in HTML5 CSS3 some javascript and jquery. Over the past 3 years I've gained an interest in the more in-depth side of UX strategics as well as the creative, I like to keep up to date with new and emerging technologies so am in the process of learning about creating web apps with react.js and also the theory and future implementation of web components in this field.

Comment: So coming from the front-end design and development side of things, at the moment I'm trying to peice together how one would create folder structures, and basically build a website using react.js on a node.js server in conjunction with HTML and CSS, and technically how these languages work together on a development and production level to create the finished product, or at least a prototype for further development.

Comment: It would be great to see a tutorial outlining the whole process with an example project, teaching the transfer between the typical process of building a front end prototype to this one via the use of node and react.

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of idioms that don't get communicated well to beginners. I help moderate a react developer community that's pretty friendly if you have questions, http://join.reactiflux.com

Comment: OK that's great, thanks Carl. Just joined. 

I'll carry on with the tutorials I'm working on and if I have any further questions pose them here or there. 

Thanks.

Comment: how would you run `npm start` forever in digital ocean even after closing the terminal

Comment: `Error: missing script: start`

Answer (score 11):

Here's official installation process: [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html), and officially recommended [tutorials](https://reactjs.org/community/courses.html)

```
# install react cli
npm install -g create-react-app

# create app
create-react-app my-react-app-name

# go to project folder
cd my-react-app-name

# install dependencies
npm install

# start live server
npm start
```

output:

```
$ You can now view my-react-app-name in the browser.

$ Local:            http://localhost:3000/
$ On Your Network:  http://192.168.0.105:3000/

$ Note that the development build is not optimized.
$ To create a production build, use npm build.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can run any one of the below mentioned commands to start the node server for your ReactJS application:

1. npm run-script **start**
2. npm run **start**
3. npm **start**

All the above commands are equivalent but people prefer the third one as it is the shortest to type on keyboard.

The **start** parameter in these commands maps to the **start** key present under **scripts** configuration present in **package.json** file of any ReactJS application. Here is a sample **package.json** file of my hello-world application:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

You can see that `react-scripts start` is written in front of **start** key. So `react-scripts start` command will get fired when we run any of the three commands which I had enlisted in the beginning e.g. `npm start`.

Answer (score 3):

I used Node to run the server. The steps I followed are:

1. I downloaded the zip package from the Running a server section
   [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)
2. I had the link open: http://localhost:3000/
3. I opened up Node.js Command Prompt and navigated to the downloaded
   zip project. From Node example [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/):

   Just type the commands in the example: 
   First npm install and then
   node server.js.

   See the screen shot below:

[image]

When I refresh the localhost web page I see the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're following the [official React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), in which case the instructions to start the various included server implementations are [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/#to-use).