# How to not get [ { "description": null } ] in PostgreSQL using react app in http://localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, frontend, backend

localhost:3000/ > Pern Todo List > type something and click Add got a bug for some reason

I use POST request from react app **add button** it should be add in whatever I type in, but I got **null** instead in Postman when using Get request

I am new to React & PostgreSQL so I don't know if I got the code right or not cause When I use Postman the Post, Delete, Get is fine but when I use Client for React App, I got this Bug:

bug **"description": null** in Postman

```js
[
    {
        "todo_id": 1,
        "description": "I need to go to work"
    },
    {
        "todo_id": 2,
        "description": "Hello meh!"
    },
    {
        "todo_id": 4,
        "description": "I need to go to the zoo"
    },
    {
        "todo_id": 5,
        "description": null
    },
```

//

For client Folder

**npx create-react-app client**

**Website That I use:**

freeCodeCamp.org

PERN Stack Course - Postgres, Express, React, and Node

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldYcgPKEZC8

**This is where I got stuck at:**

(40:59) **Build The Input Todo Component > 49:45min**

//

Yes I know how to run server & client & connect to PostgreSQL in terminal

**Run server**

```js
Cd server
Node server
Nodemon server
```

**Run client**

```js
# go to project folder
cd my-react-app-name
# start live server
npm start
```

**Open postgresSQL**

```js
psql -U postgres
\c perntodo
SELECT * FROM todos;
```

Website/Source for **Run client**:

[React tutorial - how do I start the node server for a reactJs application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758956/react-tutorial-how-do-i-start-the-node-server-for-a-reactjs-application)

//

This is the only error in console:

Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

**index.js** file < **src** < **client** < **PERN-TODO** folder

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
//Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
//https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis

//Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".
/*
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
*/
```

//

this is most of my code from **Server** folder:

for password I just put random and it work just fine in Postman, so I don't think the problem lies there

**db.js**

```js
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
    user: "postgres",
    password: "sadP002",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database: "perntodo"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

this is my Db in PostgreSQL in terminal

**database.sql**

```js
CREATE DATABASE perntodo;

CREATE TABLE todo(
    todo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(255)
);
```

//

I think the **main problem lied in client folder**

PERN-TODO folder

client folder

node_modules

public folder

Google **bootstrap 4**

**https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/**

index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

scr folder

components folder

EditTodos.js

InputTodos.js

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const InputTodo = () => {
    const [description , setDescription] = useState("");

    const onSubmitform = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const body = { description };
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5100/todos", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Constent-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });

        console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
        <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Pern Todo List</h1>
        <form className="d-flex mt-5" onSubmit={onSubmitform}>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={description}
                onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                />
            <button className="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </form>
        </Fragment>
    );
};
export default InputTodo;
```

ListTodos.js

App.css File

App.js File

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//components

import InputTodo from './components/InputTodo';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <InputTodo /> 
      </div>
      </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.css File

Index.js File

.gitignore file

Package-lock.json file

Package.json file

README.md file

Comment: Did you _look_ at this before you posted it? Please give a [mre], with correct formatting (e.g. only use snippets for code that can _actually run_ in the browser).

Comment: The title (which given its position at the top of the page and in the question list is the _first_ thing I read) is the least of the problems, and you haven't posted an answer to judge.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I haven't read the title, or why that would excuse the rest of what you've posted.

Comment: @jonsharpe that cause the first thing you do is complaint about something that are trivial, instead of helping/answer the question or ask what type of question am I asking?

Comment: It's up to _you_ to clearly communicate what type of question you're asking, see [ask] for guidance. A MRE is a basic requirement, and I don't agree that your whole post being formatted as if at random is "trivial". But it appears I've given you feedback on this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401985/server-is-declared-but-its-value-is-never-read-ts6133-with-eslint-still#comment127903744_72401985) and you've changed nothing at all, so I won't waste any more of my time here.

Comment: Please format your code and share only the minimal, reproducible example. Due to the length and confusing format of your question, you're unlikely to get any answers.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the object where the description is null and enter a new value and try again

Comment: @Wayne_Celestin are you talking about the database.sql file in server folder? or are you talking about client folder? if it client folder please tell me which file it is?

Comment: in the server folder